# Unexpected Screen in Laravel Vue3 example

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, crud

Learning by example from

https://laraveldaily.com/post/laravel-8-vue-3-crud-composition-api

and finishing the following step:

```
<x-app-layout>
    <x-slot name="header">
        ...
    </x-slot>

    <div class="py-12">
        <div class="mx-auto max-w-7xl sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="overflow-hidden bg-white shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg">
                <div class="p-6 bg-white border-b border-gray-200">
                    <router-view />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</x-app-layout>
```

Running **npm run dev** I am landing on a false screen. The text says "After logging into your Laravel Breeze, we should see this" Where would I log into "my" Laravel Breeze? (URL shows http_://localhost:5173/)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zvbwy.png) This is what is to be expected

But I am landing on

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbhSk.png) false screen

I checked routing, but I don't find a mistake.

web.php:

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'edit'])->name('profile.edit');
    Route::patch('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
    Route::delete('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'destroy'])->name('profile.destroy');
});

Route::view('/{any}', 'dashboard')
    ->middleware(['auth'])
    ->where('any', '.*');

require __DIR__.'/auth.php';
```

Comment: run php artisan serve if you didn't already run it. then access localhost:8000.

Comment: I did so, landing on the Laravel standard screen (showing the Laravel logo and the 4 offerings documentation,, Laracasts, Laravel News and Vibrant Ecosystem and two labels top right for Login, and Register).
Pressing "Log in" I receice a German error message "Fehler: Umleitungsfehler" which means Error: "Rerouting error, the website called  is rerouted in a way that can never be ended".

Comment: can I see your route file?

Comment: I have to add in top of the post, because it is too long (others routes are (api, auth, channels, console):

Comment: After deleting  Route::view('/{any}', 'dashboard') ....   from web.php  it worked.
This is contradictive to the teaching site of laraveldaily (see above), saying this statement is needed.